# Where the pid will be saved

Tags: elixir

Elixir belongs to the functional programming language family, so it is safe to say everything you feed into a function, you will get an output.

Now consider the function [register/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#register/2) from module process.

As the parameter, it expects pid, name and the return true(an atom), if everything was alright.

Where the pid will be saved? If erlang save the pids into a variable(maps, keylists) there is a share state memory and in functional programming is prohibited to save a variable into the shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're proceeding from a bad assumption.  There's nothing to say that for every parameter to a function there's a corresponding output.  That's not inherent in functional any more than it's inherent in imperative.

That said, I think the association between pid and name is stored in the Erlang Global Process Registry.  You can read more about gproc [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html).

Comment: A note: GProc is a 3rd party application, not an official part of the erlang/otp distribution.

Comment: Thanks @codypoll. Is my answer still essentially correct or do I need to edit?

Comment: Your answer is otherwise correct, but you're linking to information about a different application (GProc). I'd either edit out the last sentence containing the link, or note that it's a 3rd party implementation for doing global registry across a cluster.

Comment: Oh--I see!  Thanks @CodyPoll; I just assumed that GProc was the same as gproc.  I'll edit the link to point to the correct documentation.  Thanks for straightening me out on that point!

Answer (score 2):

Erlang is a very pragmatic language/runtime. It was never intended to be functional - it just ended up that way. Because purity wasn't its intent, several tradeoffs were made in exchange for ease of use, one example of which is the process registry. Another example is sending a message to a process - it's purely a side effect with no return value.

As for where it's stored, the VM maintains a local registry of processes in memory. Global registration across the cluster is handled by the :global module, and local registration by the :erlang.register/2 BIF (built-in function).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing state and shared state in your assertions.

In Erlang/Elixir state is not shared between multiple processes.  This is because each process has its own memory and other resources.  However, state can be saved in a separate process and queried by other processes without being shared.  There is no chance both processes will access the data at the same time causing a race condition because of messaging and the process mailbox.  Each message is queued in the mailbox and handled one at a time by the process it was sent to.  You can think of this like a web service fronting a DB that allows only a single connection at a time.

Additionally, I believe you are confusing the way Erlang/Elixir store state and the way an OO language accomplishes it.  OO languages have memory allocated from and actually store the state in the memory with a pointer to it for later access.  Erlang/Elixir store the state by a recursive process being suspended due to a `receive` function call.  Once the process is active again because a message is received, the data may be transformed.

Thus, the functional programming paradigm is not broken.  Recall, part of the paradigm is a pipeline of small functions that transform data a bit at a time.  Well, the process holding our state is still a pipeline of functions (recursive) transforming data a bit at a time.  However, that forward momentum is suspended after each step until another message is received.

Comment: In general this is correct, but the case of mapping from an atom to a registered pid is a form of global state, which does not follow Erlang's process-isolation of state semantics.

(Un/)Registering a pid is a global operation, so it mutates the registry mapping for all processes, breaking process-isolation of state and immutability. It is also a side effect, as the registration function doesn't take a registry structure as an argument, or return a modified structure. It merely returns the success of the operation.